# Html5 video poster has a delay

Tags: video, html, poster

i'm working with html5 video and noticed that, when a video ends(firing the ended event), the last image of the video is freezed for a sec or so, before showing me the poster image.

Has html5 video tag any attribute for this? Cos i want my poster to be shown right after the video ends.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ah, found it, was my fault! Poster will not show just because of video ending, you need to make another video.load() to show it, but before i empty the video .src attribute.

Well, thanks guys!